# Azure AD multitenant non-admin cant login - requires consent from admin

Tags: azure, active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I have an Azure AD multi-tenant application for which I have assigned these Graph permissions

[image: check Application permission image]

The permissions i have added doesn't require admin, then also when i try to login with a non admin user from a different tenant, it gives me following message-

> Application needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I am aware of the fact that only admin permissions require admin consent, but here if I gave this permission "Access directory as the signed in user", I still have to give admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the normal user consent applications, please ensure that the admin have enable the user consent like figure below(Azure Active Directory->User Settings):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fei for your reply. I already have that option enabled. I think the issue is that the user cannot consent himself to the app, if the app permissions require admin consent.

Comment: Instead of enable this feature in the developer tenant, this feature should be enabled in the users's tenant. Did you mean the users on in the development tenant?